# PHP Data-URI to file

Tags: php, image, file-io, data-uri

I have a data URI I am getting from javascript and trying to save via php. I use the following code which gives a apparently corrupt image file:

```
  $data = $_POST['logoImage'];

  $uri = substr($data,strpos($data,",")+1);

  file_put_contents($_POST['logoFilename'], base64_decode($uri));



data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs 9AAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAxklEQVQYlYWQMW7CUBBE33yITYUUmwbOkBtEcgUlTa7COXIVV5RUkXKC5AxU EdyZVD4kyKxkwIrr9vd0c7Oih aopinLNsF6Qkg2XW4XJ7LGFsAAcTV6lF5/jLdbALA9XDAXYfthFQVx OrmqKYK88/7rbbMFksALieTnzu9wDYTj6f70PKsp2kwAiSvjXNcvkWpAfNZkzWa/5a9yT7fdoX7rrB7hYh2fXo9HdjPYQZu3MIU8bYIlW20y0RUlXG2Kpv/vfwLxhTaSQwWqwhAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

Below the code is the actual image as a Data-URI. 'logoImage' is the string above, and $uri is the string minus 'image/jpeg;base64,'.

Comment: I'm sorry did I make a typo somewhere?

Comment: The data URI you have in your example is not a valid PNG image. This will never work and is unrelated to the code, it's related to the data.

Comment: You might want to keep that as a base64 image. I'm guessing, because I'm not a binary expert, that all of the examples given here yield a 32 bit result. As of PHP 5.2, data urls should work, so the solution could really be as simple as: `file_put_contents('logo.png', preg_replace(/\s+/, '+', $_POST['logoImage']))` if you're using the JavaScript FileReader API in conjunction with AJAX.

Comment: You really don’t have to replace any spaces with plus signs, and the accepted answer is treating a symptom without touching the cause. You just need to send properly URL-encoded data from JavaScript to your server. Also, [PHP-FileUpload](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-FileUpload) has a [`DataUriUpload`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-FileUpload/blob/023f812226673ac9e0696d8a3579bb7380606dda/src/DataUriUpload.php) component which does the rest automatically and is documented [here](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-FileUpload/tree/023f812226673ac9e0696d8a3579bb7380606dda#data-uri-uploads).

Answer (score 84, accepted):

A quick look [at the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) yields the following:

> If you want to save data that is derived from a Javascript
> `canvas.toDataURL()` function, you have to convert blanks into plusses.
> If you do not do that, the decoded data is corrupted:
>
> ```
> $encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$encodedData);
> $decodedData = base64_decode($encodedData);
> ```

Comment: This worked. Wow, I can't believe I could not find this earlier! I'll accept this as soon as I can, thanks @Graydot

Comment: This alone was not enough for me. I also had to strip everything up to the first comma, as well as the comma, before escaping the spaces with pluses:

````$decoded = Base64::decode(PHP\str_replace(' ','+',PHP\explode(',', $imageDataURL)[1]));````

Answer (score 53):

The data URI you have in your example is not a valid PNG image. This will never work and is unrelated to the code, it's related to the data.

---

Does not apply but might be of interest:

```
file_put_contents($_POST['logoFilename'], file_get_contents($data));
```

The idea behind: PHP itself can read the contents of [data URIs (`data://`)](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php) so you don't need to decode it on your own.

Note that the official data URI scheme (ref: [The "data" URL scheme RFC 2397](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397)) does not include a double slash ("`//`") after the colon ("`:`"). PHP supports with or without the two slashes.

```
 # RFC 2397 conform
 $binary = file_get_contents($uri);

 # with two slashes
 $uriPhp = 'data://' . substr($uri, 5);
 $binary = file_get_contents($uriPhp);
```

Comment: And finally: `file_put_contents($_POST['logoFilename'], $binary);`

Comment: We're on PHP 5.5.25, and it seems it is not necessary to add the double slashes.

Comment: @Andz: Looks like with PHP 5.2+ this always worked: http://3v4l.org/Fk4RY - very nice Comment on PHP.net is years old, too. Don't trust the map, trust the terrain, thanks again for the hint. Corrected the answer.

Comment: This is a great answer, no idea this was built-in!

Comment: Your solution did not work for me. I have tried file_put_contents('https://www.instagram.com/nasa/?__a=1') but does not work.

Answer (score 37):

The all code that works :

```
$imgData = str_replace(' ','+',$_POST['image']);
$imgData =  substr($imgData,strpos($imgData,",")+1);
$imgData = base64_decode($imgData);
// Path where the image is going to be saved
$filePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/ima/temp2.png';
// Write $imgData into the image file
$file = fopen($filePath, 'w');
fwrite($file, $imgData);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: !! I have tried a TON of answers on SO and elsewhere, and this is the only thing that worked! It worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have another way to do this with PHP.

```
$img = str_replace(' ','+',$img);
$i = explode(',', $img);
$imgData = array_pop($i);
$newName = 'digital_file/'. rand(10, 16) . '.' . str_replace('/', '.', mime_content_type($img) );
// data:image/png;base64
$imgData = base64_decode($imgData);
```

Now you can use `file_put_contents($newName)` to create the image file.
Produces a file with a random numerical name (e.g. "123123.image.png"). And of course it has correct mime type.