# How to save a base64 decoded image in the filesystem using php?

Tags: php, web-services, base64

I am getting a base64 encoded JPEG string via a POST request to my web service. 
I want to decode it and save it in the filesystem. 
How can I achieve this using PHP 5.3. 
I am able to successfully decode the data using the base64_decode function.

How can I save this decoded string as a JPEG image in the server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u try to save this in a binary file using fopen ?

Comment: @Arfeen Thanks, I tried file_put_contents() and it worked. I came here to update my question to notice that your and Lawrence Cherone's comments.

Comment: As a general solution that is much more flexible and powerful, [PHP-FileUpload](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-FileUpload/tree/master) comes with both [`Base64Upload`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-FileUpload/blob/7c950635cbd45ade9fb2656eb285259dc2a8f0fb/src/Base64Upload.php) and [`DataUriUpload`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-FileUpload/blob/7c950635cbd45ade9fb2656eb285259dc2a8f0fb/src/DataUriUpload.php), which are [documented here](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-FileUpload/blob/master/README.md#usage).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are sure the image will always be jpg then you can simply use: [file_put_contents();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
<?php 
$decoded=base64_decode($encodedString);

file_put_contents('newImage.JPG',$decoded);
//leave it to you to randomize the filename.
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. However its not guaranteed to always be a JPEG. I'll try and see if I can get it from the MIME type. :) Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 8):

Replacing the blank spaces with + signs is required if the data is derived from canvas.toDataURL() function.

```
 $encodedString = str_replace(' ','+',$encodedString);
```

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6735480/1346271)

It helped a lot in my case.