# Error while trying to generate Image using base64_decode

Tags: php

I am trying to generate an image using `base64_decode` with png extension, but generated png image is wrong, it is showing "invalid image".

my code is below

```
$base_64 = $this->input->post('base_64');
$decoded_base_64 = base64_decode($base_64);
$result = file_put_contents('directory/toSaveImage/' . $id . '.png', $decoded_base_64);
```

While searching for the solution i also tried adding before the $result variable.

```
    header("Content-type: image/png");
```

I also did try this line though

```
    $decoded_base_64 = base64_decode(base64_encode($base_64));
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252925/how-to-save-a-base64-decoded-image-in-the-filesystem-using-php

Comment: This line $decoded_base_64 = base64_decode(base64_encode($base_64)); no make sense

Comment: If you `cat` an image does it return base64 or an error or anything?

Comment: @JordanDoyle yes it does

Comment: @rafi_ccj what does it return? EDIT: lets rewind a little bit, what does `var_dump($this->input->post('base_64'));` return? Pastebin it if it's too big.

Comment: @JordanDoyle - data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABdQAAASACAYAAAD22c+oAAAgAElEQVR4nOzd+3PW9Z338eyMs60HIJDrmCtXIFG27iy17Qr2BtxtRa0VMAwGMEQQEA.................
http://pastebin.com/G7qA7nAQ

Comment: @rafi_ccj that's not a raw image file. Do you need it to be a raw image file? If not you can echo it in the `src` attribute of an `img` tag. - this is your image, right? http://i.imgur.com/fHFHYxl.png

Comment: @JordanDoyle i am decoding it into base64 ... shouldn't that work?

Comment: Answered your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your answer:

```
<?php
    $base64 = $this->input->post('base_64');
    $base64 = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $base64);
    file_put_contents("directory/toSaveImage/{$id}.png", base64_decode($base64));
```

You weren't removing `data:image/png;base64,`