# How can I upload image in Yii from canvas with toDataURL()

Tags: html, file-upload, canvas, yii

How should I get image from canvas to CUploadedFile::getInstance? or is there any way how to save image from canvas in Yii?

I have this:

```
  var canvas=document.getElementById("photoCanvas");
  photoData=canvas.toDataURL();
```

and I am using Ajax to get photoData to php, I aslo know how to save it onve it's loaded in CUploadedFile::getInstance

```
  $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../images/'.$fileName);
```

but what should be between these two codes? how should I save $_POST['photoData'] to $uploadedFile?

**Simplified:** How to get url image to CUploadedFile?

Answer (score 0):

It is not using `$_FILES` as would with classic file upload, if you have that data in `$_POST['photoData']` simply use `file_put_contents` (decode first, see footnote):

```
file_put_contents(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../images/'.$fileName, $_POST['photoData']);
```

For decoding see [PHP Data-URI to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735414/php-data-uri-to-file)