# how to convert data URI to file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra, data-uri

How do I convert a data URI that comes from the result of the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) into an image file that can be saved in the file system in Ruby?

What I'm currently trying to do is using base64 decode to convert the data_uri string which looks like this: `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgA...` into base 64 encoded string because according to this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735414/php-data-uri-to-file) I need to replace all the instances of spaces into `+`. The answer is in PHP but I'm currently working on Ruby and Sinatra so I'm not sure if it still applies, but when using the equivalent code:

```
src = data_uri.gsub! ' ', '+'
src = Base64.decode64(src)
f = File.new('uploads/' + 'sample.png', "w")
f.write(src)
f.close
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `unpack' for nil:NilClass
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to be able to convert the data URI to a file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no need to reinvent the wheel. Use the [data_uri](https://github.com/dball/data_uri) gem.

```
require 'data_uri'

uri = URI::Data.new('data:image/gif;base64,...')
File.write('uploads/file.jpg', uri.data)
```

Comment: I'm working with RMagick and image blobs, the `data_uri` gem worked for me. Thanks