# I have a DataUrl of a file.. how to pass this dataurl for the iframe file upload (IE9)

Tags: javascript, iframe, file-upload, internet-explorer-9

data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/f3//Ub//ge
8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67QZ1h
LnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcppV0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g
77ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNgYPj/gAwXEQA7

This is the DataUri of an gif image.

I wanna upload this gif file by using datauri to my server location. 
I am currently working on IE 9 which doesn't support the BLOB or FILEAPI

So i have only one alternative, iframe file upload.
Is this possible to upload the gif file using DataUri , by iframe method

Thanks you in beforehand

Comment: Is requirement to post `data URI` string to server , or set `iframe` `src` property to `data URI` ?

Comment: yes i need to post data URI string to server and File to be uploaded to specific folder at my server.

As i am working with IE9. No BLOB , No FILE 
I Need support to solve this.

Comment: How is `data URI` string defined at `html` , `js` ?

Comment: in JS, I have got that from Javascript

Comment: Can include portion of `js` where `data URI` is set as variable at Question ?

Comment: yes, Sure 

 var url = 'data:application/pdf;base64,'+btoa(rawDocument);


i have used the PDFJS

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735414/php-data-uri-to-file

Comment: yes, this kind of thing is possible.

i have the doubt, that this data uri can be passed as file?