# Upload image to server from data uri

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, summernote

I am using the summernote text editor ( http://summernote.org/ )

As you can try there a way to upload images from your computer, can be tried on the website. I have then trouble saving these pictures to the server after the user sends the data of the textbloc ..
What i did try was to capture the data uri with a regex, then code it with php into a file but that doesent work
Wich is the best way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably this answer will help:

[PHP Data-URI to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735414/php-data-uri-to-file)

You probably forgot to base64_decode the data?

Comment: i tried with a test string, didn't work out
I will try with what you sent and tell the result; in fact i was wondering if they were better ways of doing what i wanted, knowing that my method have backdraws like the unability to transmit these "links" with post variable unless i make their size bigger, wich is unsafe

Comment: Would you mind providing more details of what you tried and what failed? This would help in trying to help