# Send image using XMLHttpRequest and grab with php

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Im using webcam to capture user profile picture, and then i upload the image to server using XMLHttpRequest like so:

```
document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var image = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('picture', image);
    request.open('POST', 'upload.php');
    request.onload = function () {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            console.log('all done: ');
        } else {
            console.log('Nope');
        }
    };
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    request.send(fd);
});
```

Im not using a form, im getting image from canva html element in this line:

```
var image = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
```

I think is all ok with the js part, the console shows that the data is sent.
In php i try to manipulate the image and store to a server directory like so:

```
<?php
$info = pathinfo($_FILES['picture']['name']);
$ext = $info['extension']; // get the extension of the file
$newname = "perfil.".$ext; 

$target = 'uploads/'.$newname;
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $target);
?>
```

But the image is nos actually stored in the folder specified in the code above, i dont know what im doing wrong or if something escaped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> var image = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
>                    ^^^^^^^^^
> ```

You are getting a data URL. This is not a file.

> ```
> $info = pathinfo($_FILES['picture']['name']);
> ```

Since it isn't a file, it won't be in `$_FILES` or have a file name.

You can read the data from `$_POST['picture']`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735414/php-data-uri-to-file) then covers the process of converting a data URL to a file.

Comment: Oh yes, thats it...i was not getting a file, thank you!

Comment: Im following the post you sugested, but now im getting an empty image file, with 0kb.